# what is the equivalent command of below command used in mysql database to insert a CSV file in a database

Tags: mysql

what is the equivalent command of below command used in mysql database to insert a CSV file in a database.

```
cat Master.csv.2011-03-02-16-44-29 | tr \" \' | psql -U postgres cdr
```

The above command is used to insert a CSV(cooma-seperated value) file in the Postgresql database.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
            --fields-terminated-by=, \
            --local -u root \
            -p Database \
             Master.csv.2011-03-02-16-44-29
```

For replacing the double quotes you can replace them previously:

```
cat Master.csv.2011-03-02-16-44-29 | tr \" \' > newFile.csv
```

And then insert this file with `mysqlimport` command.

Also consider using `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` if you use the quotes as enclosing characters used in the column data itself.